# GetCallingAssembly different when attacked to visual studio vs standalone

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got a strange problem with GetCallingAssembly... I've a main WPF application that loads data from different assemblies looking on implemented interface.
When I execute the code under VS (release) I got the correct callingassembly 
(ex. Modules.Calendar , Modules.Reporting and so on).
When I run it from standalone (release) I got the CallingAssembly that points to main WPF application's exe and so it won't perform correctly it's duties (That in this specific case is to load menu items)

Each module implements the following code

```
public class MenuRegisterService : MenuRegisterServiceBase
{
 Assembly.GetCallingAssembly() correctly filled
    public override Task<MenuItemNode> RegisterMenu(ICollection<string> functions)
    {
        return base.RegisterMenu(functions);
    }
}
```

and here's the Base method

```
public virtual Task<MenuItemNode> RegisterMenu(ICollection<string> functions)
    {

        try
        {
            var assembly = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly(); //I should get the module that invoked the base class

            log.Info("->" + assembly.FullName);
            string filename = GetFullFileName(assembly, MenuFilename);

            return Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                string xmlFileName = string.Format(filename);

                var doc = new XmlDocument();

                using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(xmlFileName))
                {
                    if (stream != null)
                    {
                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                        {
                            doc.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd());
                        }
                    }
                }

                MenuItemNode menu = BuildMenu(doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/Node"), functions);

                return menu;
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

          log.Error(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may some unexpected behavior with inlined methods.

Read this from MSDN:

> If the method that calls the GetCallingAssembly method is expanded inline by the just-in-time (JIT) compiler, or if its caller is expanded inline, the assembly that is returned by GetCallingAssembly may differ unexpectedly.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getcallingassembly.aspx)

You can try decorating the method with ImplOptions.NoInlining:

```
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
public virtual Task<MenuItemNode> RegisterMenu(ICollection<string> functions)
```

But I'm not sure if it will work correctly if the return value is a `Task<T>`. The reason you aren't seeing it when running in Debug mode is because the JIT doesn't inline methods in Debug mode.